# How to Compare two rows using a cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have a simple problem where I want to compare the current row with the previous one and if they are the same then out the RowID.  Alos when I print @abc and @abc2 why they give me the same result.?

**Following is my code:**

```
DECLARE 
             @abc float,
             @def datetime,

             @abc2 float,
             @def2 datetime


DECLARE  downTime SCROLL CURSOR  FOR
select D_ABC, D_DEF   

OPEN downTime
   FETCH First FROM downTime INTO @abc,@def 
   FETCH NEXT FROM downTime INTO  @abc2,@def2 

   print @abc
   print @abc2


      WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

        BEGIN   

               // Out here I want to print the rowID's of those rows where @abc = @abc2

       END
CLOSE downTime
```

Comment: Where does the new row come from? And what do you mean by "the previous one"?

Comment: Don't need a CURSOR. What does the table look like please?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cursor

- For each row, get the previous one
- Compare them

Something like

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   myTable M
   CROSS APPLY
   (--get previous row
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM myTable M2
    WHERE M2.ID < M.ID
    ORDER BY M2.ID
   ) foo
WHERE --compare
   foo.col1 = M.col1 AND foo.col2 = M.col2 etc
```

Slightly less exact (that it, you'll get false positives)

```
...
WHERE
  CHECKSUM(M.*) <> CHECKSUM(foo.*)
```